# Spark cluster mode on Mesos: how to pass configuration to executor?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, mesos

I am testing the use of Docker for executing Spark algorithms on MESOS. I managed to execute Spark in client mode with executors inside Docker, but I wanted to go further and have also my Driver running into a Docker Container. Here I ran into a behavior that I'm not sure is normal, let me try to explain.

I submit my spark application through MesosClusterDispatcher using a command like:

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master mesos://spark-master-1:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.mesos.executor.docker.image=myuser/myimage:0.0.2 https://storage.googleapis.com/some-bucket/spark-examples-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar 10
```

My driver is running fine, inside its docker container, but the executors fail:

```
"sh: /some/spark/home/bin/spark-class: No such file or directory"
```

Looking on MESOS slaves log, I think that the executors do not run inside docker: "`docker.cpp:775] No container info found, skipping launch`". As my Mesos slaves do not have spark installed, it fails.

It seems that the spark conf that I gave in the first spark-submit is not transmitted to the Driver submitted conf, when launched in the docker container. The only workaround I found is to modify my Docker image in order to define inside its spark conf the `spark.mesos.executor.docker.image` property. This way, my executors get the conf well and are launched inside docker on Mesos. This seems a little complicated to me, and I feel the configuration passed to the early spark-submit should be transmitted to the Driver submit...

So my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a better solution to transmit spark configuration from before the mesos-dispatcher to the executor through the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13258

:-)

I'll be fixing this soon.  The workaround, as described in the JIRA, is to use `SPARK_JAVA_OPTS` rather than `--conf`.